# Laravel 5 add attribute to User model before login

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to add a custom attribute to the User model when the user logs in. This value is not in the database so needs to be added after.

The attribute I need to add is called `client_id`

I've search everywhere for a solution but everything I've tried doesn't work.  When I dump out the user in another controller, I don't see the attribute I added.

I've stripped out everything that I tried and I'm left with the original model.

Here is my User model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    protected $appends = ['client_id'];

    public function getClientIdAttribute()
    {
        // get the orgId from the session
        $client_id = \Session::get('client_id');

        return $client_id;
    }
}
```

And here is my LoginContorller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \DB;
// Models
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
     }

     public function login(Request $request)
     {
         // Check validation
         $this->validate($request, [
             'username' => 'required|regex:/^([a-z0-9-_\.]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)$/',
             'password' => 'required'
         ]);

        $user = User::where('username', $request->input('username'))
            ->where('isActive', 1)
            ->first();

        // Set Auth Details
        \Auth::login($user);

        // Redirect home page
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

I tied adding an attribute using `$user->setAtttribute('client_id', 12345);` before `\Auth::login($user);` but it didn't work

Comment: so before login what is $user then ?

Answer (score -1):

#### Using Accessors

You can create a dynamic attribute in your User model like this.

```
public function getClientIdAttribute(){

// Write code to return the client ID here

}
```

Then you can get this value for any user by doing `$user->client_id`

#### Using Sessions

You can store a value for any authenticated user. You can use the global Laravel `session()` helper anywhere in your application like this:

```
// Storing / Setting a Value
session(['client_id' => '12345']);

// Retrieving a Value
session('client_id');
```

Comment: But how do i set the attribute in the first place?

Comment: You don't really have to "set" it. For example if inside of this function I do something like ```return $this->username . '123';```. Then ```$user->client_id``` would return ```john123``` or ```peter123``` depending on the user. How is your client_id being generated? PS: You can read more about accessors here: [Laravel Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: I guess this works with normal models but I haven't seen example that does it with a user model especially one that ```extends Authenticatable```

Comment: Yeah I tried it and it dumped out null. I could see the appends key but when dumping....nothing

Comment: I currently use Accessors on the User models on all my Laravel apps (they extend Authenticatable too). Could you post your code in your question?

Comment: I mean include the `getClientIdAttribute` function you tried to use. You're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Updated the model show show my accessor. I not set a session in the controller and get it that way but would rather do it the way i wanted

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the Sessions method if you want to do it that way.